# Powers of a $2 \times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix such that $$A = \begin{pmatrix} \sin\frac{\pi}{18} & -\sin\frac{4\pi}{9} \\ \sin\frac{4\pi}{9} & \sin\frac{\pi}{18} \end{pmatrix}$$ Find the smallest number $n \in N$ such that $A^n = I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix of order $2$.

Comment: *Hint*: $\sin\frac{\pi}{18}=\cos\left(\frac49\pi\right)$

Comment: As hinted by the above comment, the matrix is a rotation matrix.

Comment: @G. Sassatelli: And conversely.

Comment: You may also first find the eigenvalues of the matrix and look for the least $n$ such that the $n$-th power of both eigenvalues are 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the identity $\sin\theta=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)$, you get $\sin\frac{\pi}{18}=\cos\frac{4\pi}{9}$.

Substitute this in and you get your standard rotation matrix:
$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\frac{4}{9}\pi & -\sin\frac{4}{9}\pi \\ 
\sin\frac{4}{9}\pi  & \cos\frac{4}{9}\pi 
\end{pmatrix}$

This is equivalent to a counterclockwise rotation of $\frac{4}{9}\pi$. How many times do you need to apply this rotation so that you are back to where you started?

As $4$ and $9$ are coprime, you will need to do it $9$ times. Hence, $n=9$.

Comment: best answer I saw today! Thanks +1.

Comment: Aren't you using $\sin\theta=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)$?

Comment: Yes, you're right, thanks for noticing, I've edited the answer now